# bad result findHomography

Tags: opencv, camera, android

I'm using opencv4android 3.2, to find a known object I'm using `findHomography` method and, when I capture an image where the object farther away from the camera it gives me a good result, but when I capture an image where the object closer away from the camera I got a bad result.

- object to find

[image: the object card to detect taken from the camera]

- result

[image: the result of homography]

this is my code

```
       // Matches current frame's descriptors to template's
            descriptorMatcher.match(descriptors, templateDescriptors, 
            matches);

            List<DMatch> matchesList = matches.toList();
            double maxDistance = 0;
            double minDistance = 100;
            int rowCount = descriptors.rows();
            for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
                double dist = matchesList.get(i).distance;
                if (dist < minDistance) minDistance = dist;
                if (dist > maxDistance) maxDistance = dist;
            }

       List<DMatch> goodMatchesList = new ArrayList<>();


        double upperBound = 3 * minDistance;
            for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
                if (matchesList.get(i).distance <= upperBound) {
                    goodMatchesList.add(matchesList.get(i));
                }
            }


            // Iterate through good matches and put the 2D points of the 
            object (template) and frame (scene) into a list
            List<KeyPoint> objKpList = new ArrayList<>();
            List<KeyPoint> sceneKpList = new ArrayList<>();
            objKpList = templateKeypoints.toList();
            sceneKpList = keypoints.toList();
            LinkedList<Point> objList = new LinkedList<>();
            LinkedList<Point> sceneList = new LinkedList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < goodMatchesList.size(); i++) {

     objList.addLast(objKpList.get(goodMatchesList.get(i).trainIdx).pt);
     sceneList.addLast(sceneKpList.get(goodMatchesList.get(i).queryIdx).pt);
   }

            MatOfPoint2f obj = new MatOfPoint2f();
            MatOfPoint2f scene = new MatOfPoint2f();

            obj.fromList(objList);
            scene.fromList(sceneList);

            // Calculate the homography
            Mat H = Calib3d.findHomography(obj, scene, Calib3d.RANSAC, 3);

          ...

       try {
                Core.perspectiveTransform(objCorners, sceneCorners, H);
                Point p1 = new Point(sceneCorners.get(0, 0));
                Point p2 = new Point(sceneCorners.get(1, 0));
                Point p3 = new Point(sceneCorners.get(2, 0));
                Point p4 = new Point(sceneCorners.get(3, 0));

                final List<Point> source = new ArrayList<Point>();
                    source.add(p1);
                    source.add(p2);
                    source.add(p3);
                    source.add(p4);
               Mat startM = Converters.vector_Point2f_to_Mat(source);
               flip(startM, startM, -1);
               Mat result = warp(rgba, startM);

               Bitmap bmppp = Bitmap.createBitmap(result.width(), 
               result.height(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
               Utils.matToBitmap(result, bmppp);
               keypoints.release();
               SaveImage(result);

            } catch (CvException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

                Log.e(TAG, "perspectiveTransform returned an assertion 
                failed error.");
                return false;
                }
```

why i don't got the good result findHomography?

Thanks.

this is the template using to find the card object [image]

Comment: Can you fix your spacing in the code? It's very hard to read currently. Also this is a huge chunk of code, it would be in general much better to post a [minimal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) verifiable example. Additionally, it would be helpful to post your template. Also, your question doesn't really make sense; what do you mean by "limit"? `findHomography` will work at most scales. If `findHomography` is off, it's likely you don't have good matches to start with.

Comment: what does mean findhomography off ? check the edit i added the template and for information i'm using ORB for the FeatureDetector and DescriptorExtractor @AlexanderReynolds

Comment: By `off` I mean that the result is wrong; to rephrase, "If `findHomography` is not giving a good homography, it's likely you don't have good matches to start with." You might want to reupload that template as the barcode is still visible. Are you trying to match that particular ID with the exact same one in the frame, or are you hoping to match other IDs with that one? Because if you're trying to use one ID to match with a different ID, you might get matching features that don't necessarily line up in the image (for example two of the same letters might match but be in different places).

Comment: thanks for reply, i got a bad matchs only when i cpature the object closer, but when i capture an image where the object farther away from the camera it gives me a good result, so i want to understand the problem 
 @AlexanderReynolds

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. It sounds silly, but have you tried to switch the srcPoints with destinationPoints?

I'm using homography to control the navigation of a robot. I originally had:

```
M, mask = cv2.findHomography(robotPoints, visionpoints)
```

However, by switching the robotPoints with the visionPoints it worked. I was reverse mapping the planes.

```
M, mask = cv2.findHomography(visionPoints,robotPoints)
```